# TableSorter with dynamic format function in addParser

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using TableSorter on a column that contains a string:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser(
    {
        id: 'positions',
        is: function(s) {
                return false;
            },
        format: function(s) {
                var abbr=s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').slice(_sortpos);
                return abbr;
            },
        type: 'numeric'
    }
);
```

The format function should return a value dependent on the global _sortpos variable. This value changes dynamically. The line:

```
var abbr=s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').slice(_sortpos);
```

strips all non-numbers and non-letters and then removes a certain number of initial characters. The intend is to sort by the  _sortpos-th character.

What seems to happen is, that the format function is only parsed once for each string when the parser is added to the table sorter. However for my purposes it would have to re-run the format function every time I am sorting.

So far I've tried adding the parser every time I sort. But that did not work. I also tried to re-initialise the tablesorter by re-running my initialisation

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter(
    {
        sortReset: true,
        headers: {
            1: {
                sorter: 'positions'
            }
        }
    }   
);
```

but to no avail.

What could I do? Also: Is there a comparator function that I could use to sneak in a global parameter? I could then format the string in the parser and then use _sortpos in the slice()-function dynamically in the comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer myself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter(
        {
            textSorter: function(a, b, table, column){                  
                if (column==1)
                {
                    var c=parseInt(a.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').slice(_sortpos));
                    var d=parseInt(b.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').slice(_sortpos));                 
                    return ((c < d) ? -1 : ((c > d) ? 1 : 0));
                }
                return a.localeCompare(b);              
            }           
        }
    );  
});
```

It does not use a parser and sorts only column==1 with the custom sorter.

Comment: As I did not get an answer, but mine, I'll soon accept it. I am still not sure if what I am doing is as intended or a hack.